# Choosing relevant traits

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence

I am trying to create a classifier for the following problem:

> Given a patient diagnosed with glioblastoma multiforme and his age, cluster of the disease and ~16 000 of traits related to the patient's genes, predict whether the patient will survive a year after the diagnosis

As dark as it is a task, I'm on the first stage of solving it and having some trouble. I would like to distinguish the genes which *appear* to be relevant to the variable which states whether a patient survives - but I don't know how to distinguish those traits which are dependent of whether the patient died after one year.

Is there any test (possibly already implemented in R) which tests for independence between a discrete random variable (true or false - did the patient die after one year) and a continuous variable (values for some gene - I don't understand this variable's meaning)?

The training data can be found [here (txt)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbiecek/StatystykaII/master/MIMUW_2017/materialy/GlioblastomaWide.txt) or [here (rda)](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbiecek/StatystykaII/master/MIMUW_2017/materialy/GlioblastomaWide.rda) - it's not too big

I'd appreciate some help

Answer (score 1):

This may be a complicated task that has not one simple and unique answer. A good place to start would be a decision tree. CART algorithms tells you to look into 5 out of your 16thousand variables first. After installing the apropriate libraries, try the following:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

genes <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pbiecek/StatystykaII/master/MIMUW_2017/materialy/GlioblastomaWide.txt", sep=";")

genes2 <- genes; genes2$sampleID <- NULL #get rid of sampleID column
decision.tree <- rpart(death1y ~ ., data=genes2)
prp(decision.tree)  # pretty print the tree generated by rpart
```

Comment: Just to clarify; I'm not yet trying to build the classifier - first, I would like to somehow discard all the data that appears to be irrelevant - and do it myself. But from your answer it truly appears that those five genes are the only ones dependent - not even the age. Could it be?

Comment: No, things are far more complicated: Imagine, all 16.000 variables were random. In so many random variables, some will coincidentally be correlated with the survival. 125 observations are a small number for this amount of variables. You may consider splitting the dataset in one for training of some classifier (potentially a tree) and one for testing. Unfortunately, this leaves you with an even smaller training data set for still 16.000 variables. As I said, this is a complicated task and will not be within the scope of what can be explained in a forum. You will have to read a good book or two.

Comment: Maybe look at http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf to see, if it is a good start for you. Look at chapter 5.1 and chapter 8 first.